# How to extract each line which matches only first occurrence of particular character in that line?

Tags: regex, grep

I am working on a bash shell script. I have a variable which have a number of lines. Here:  **how can I extract each line which matches character 5 in column 5** ?

`declare -a T1
echo '$input'
T=$(echo -e "$input" | grep 5)
echo "$T"`

**input variable content:**

```
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 4
:: find lo(): [6] :: Current Digital = 0.00 4
:: find lo(): [7] :: Current Digital = 0.00 5
:: find lo(): [8] :: Current Digital = 0.00 4
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 7
:: find lo(): [6] :: Current Digital = 0.00 7
:: find lo(): [7] :: Current Digital = 0.00 15
:: find lo(): [8] :: Current Digital = 0.00 7
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 10
:: find lo(): [6] :: Current Digital = 0.00 10
:: find lo(): [7] :: Current Digital = 0.00 10
:: find lo(): [8] :: Current Digital = 0.00 35
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 13
:: find lo(): [6] :: Current Digital = 0.00 25
:: find lo(): [7] :: Current Digital = 0.00 13
:: find lo(): [8] :: Current Digital = 0.00 13
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 15
:: find lo(): [6] :: Current Digital = 0.00 50
:: find lo(): [7] :: Current Digital = 0.00 16
:: find lo(): [8] :: Current Digital = 0.00 55
```

**Expected T1 variable content:**

```
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 4
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 7
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 10
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 13
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 15
```

**Current T1 variable content:**

```
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 4
:: find lo(): [7] :: Current Digital = 0.00 5
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 7
:: find lo(): [7] :: Current Digital = 0.00 15
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 10
:: find lo(): [8] :: Current Digital = 0.00 35
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 13
:: find lo(): [5] :: Current Digital = 0.00 15
:: find lo(): [6] :: Current Digital = 0.00 50
:: find lo(): [8] :: Current Digital = 0.00 55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command should give you the expected output as long as the first occurrence of 5 is always in enclosed brackets.

```
T=$(echo -e "$input" | grep '\[5\]'))
```